# Maven multimodule versioning - package does not exist

Tags: java, spring, maven

Currently trying to create a multi-module project with ProjectMaster as parent POM, and ProjectAPI and ProjectUI as its modules.

I created a class in ProjectAPI to generate a key to pass it to the ProjectUI.

```
package com.ext.sample.ProjectAPI.util;

public class KeyGen {

    public KeyGenData keyData;

    @Autowired
    public KeyGen (KeyGenData keyData) {
        this.keyData= keyData;
    }

    public String KeyGenerator() {
        // key gen code
    }
}
```

Now, I've passed my API's info to my UI's POM

**API POM**

```
    <groupId>com.ext.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>ProjectAPI</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
```

**UI POM**

```
<!-- Project dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ext.sample</groupId>
            <artifactId>ProjectAPI</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
```

I've already imported the API's class to where I'm using in the UI, no errors come up in Netbeans and Eclipse, but when I clean and build, they still return a compilation error.

```
com/ext/sample/ProjectUI/web/HomeController.java:[11,27] package com.ext.sample.ProjectAPI.util does not exist
com/ext/sample/ProjectUI/web/HomeController.java:[73,16] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class KeyGen
  location: class com.ext.sample.ProjectUI.web.HomeController
```

```
import com.ext.sample.ProjectAPI.util.KeyGen;

@Controller
public class HomeController {
   public KeyGen kg;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getKey", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String getKey() {
        String key = kg.KeyGenerator();

        return key;
    }
```

Appreciate any help you can give.

Comment: You do realize 1.0 and 1.0-SNAPSHOT are not the same, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your versioning is broken. Your API has version 1.0 while your UI tries to use 1.0-SNAPSHOT. If this artifact even exists (from prevoius attempts) it not updated at all.

The common solution to this is to define one project version in the parent pom and not to define any version in the child project, thus inheriting the parent projects version.